# Extracting 10 popular user from twitter with twitter api

Tags: python, stopiteration

I am trying to extract 10 popular(verified) users from Twitter which I follow but every time I am getting an error the error is
RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration.
I am new to python and don't know where the code is wrong, so I am posting the whole code.

````
    def limitt(pointerss, list_name):
        while True:
            try:
                yield pointerss.next()
            except tweepy.RateLimitError:
                print("\nData points in list = {}".format(len(list_name)))
                print('Hit Twitter API rate limit.')
                for i in range(3, 0, -1):
                    print("Wait for {} mins.".format(i * 5))
                    time.sleep(5 * 60)

            except tweepy.error.TweepError:
                print('\nCaught TweepError exception')

    
    def extracting_popular_user():

        following_list = []
        cursor = tweepy.Cursor(api.friends, count=10).pages()
        for i, page in enumerate(limitt(cursor, following_list)):
            following_list += page
# print(type(following_list))
        following_list = [x._json for x in following_list]
# print("hello")
        print(len(following_list))
        for i in range(0, len(following_list)):
            screen_name = following_list[i]['screen_name']
            followers_count = following_list[i]['followers_count']
            statuses_count = following_list[i]['statuses_count']
            verified = following_list[i]['verified']
            if verified == True and followers_count > 10000 and statuses_count > 5000:
                with open("file.txt", "a") as f:
                    f.write("%s \n" % (screen_name))
            with open("file.txt", "r") as f1:
                accounts = f1.readlines()
            if len(accounts) == 10:
                break

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(" ", " ") # enter twitter key
        auth.set_access_token(" ", "")      # enter twitter access token

        api = tweepy.API(auth)

        extracting_popular_user()```
````

**I am getting the following error       RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration. I have tried multiple times but still not getting the result. So need help.**

```
     ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-10-6e4a410414db> in limitt(pointerss, list_name)
         13         try:
    ---> 14             yield pointerss.next()
         15 

    2 frames
    StopIteration: 

    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-10-6e4a410414db> in extracting_popular_user()
         29     following_list = []
         30     cursor = tweepy.Cursor(api.friends, count=10).pages()
    ---> 31     for i, page in enumerate(limitt(cursor, following_list)):
         32         following_list += page
         33     # print(type(following_list))

    RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
```